# MySQL group-by query perfomance improved by adding aggregation

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `pv_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `has_data` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

ALTER TABLE `events`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pv_name`,`time_stamp`),
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `has_data` (`pv_name`,`has_data`,`time_stamp`);
```

I am trying to find the distinct set of pv_names that have some row with no data between two given times. Both of the following queries appear to return this information:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pv_name FROM events
         WHERE has_data = 0
           AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999
         GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 251     | NULL | 1855281 |     1.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events
         WHERE has_data = 0
           AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999
         GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 251     | NULL | 203123 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

What I do not understand is why the second query, which has an extra restriction on what it returns (that I do not need), appears to run in less time than the first. Is there a way to improve the first query to match the efficiency of the second without the aggregation on the `time_stamp` column?

EDIT:

Per Rick James's suggestion I changed the `has_data` index:

```
ALTER TABLE `events`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pv_name`,`time_stamp`), ADD KEY `has_data` (`has_data`,`pv_name`,`time_stamp`);
```

This changed the query reports to:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 1       | const | 267096 |    11.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 1       | const | 267096 |    11.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

This seems to run faster.

EDIT:

Results for test requested by Rick James:

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
.
.
.
114480 rows in set (0.34 sec)

mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| Handler_commit             | 1      |
| Handler_delete             | 0      |
| Handler_discover           | 0      |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2      |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0      |
| Handler_prepare            | 0      |
| Handler_read_first         | 0      |
| Handler_read_key           | 1      |
| Handler_read_last          | 0      |
| Handler_read_next          | 125527 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0      |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0      |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0      |
| Handler_rollback           | 0      |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0      |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0      |
| Handler_update             | 0      |
| Handler_write              | 0      |
+----------------------------+--------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  3683887 |
+----------+
1 row in set (11.66 sec)
```

EDIT:

Timings of runs:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM events;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| events |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | pv_name     | A         |      216061 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | time_stamp  | A         |     4450791 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          1 | has_data |            1 | has_data    | A         |         258 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          1 | has_data |            2 | pv_name     | A         |      496542 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          1 | has_data |            3 | time_stamp  | A         |     4390035 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT events.pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 1       | const | 267096 |    11.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 1       | const | 267096 |    11.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


SELECT events.pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
114480 rows in set (0.37 sec)

SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
114480 rows in set (0.30 sec)


mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM events;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| events |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | pv_name     | A         |      422951 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | time_stamp  | A         |     4321990 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          0 | has_data |            1 | pv_name     | A         |      240067 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          0 | has_data |            2 | has_data    | A         |      436525 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| events |          0 | has_data |            3 | time_stamp  | A         |     4205163 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT events.pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 251     | NULL | 4462633 |     1.11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,has_data | has_data | 251     | NULL | 240076 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

SELECT events.pv_name FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
114480 rows in set (6.79 sec)

SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) FROM events WHERE has_data = 0 AND events.time_stamp > 0 AND events.time_stamp < 9999999999999999999 GROUP BY events.pv_name;
114480 rows in set (2.65 sec)
```

Comment: If you repeat both queries now that the table has read data into the buffer pool, are both queries fast? It's often the case that the first time you run a query, it's slower than subsequent times you run the same query, because it has to populate the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html for loose-index scan):

*Any other parts of the index than those from the GROUP BY referenced in the query must be constants (that is, they must be referenced in equalities with constants), except for the argument of MIN() or MAX() functions*.

In your first query, time_stamp is referenced but not constant. In your second query, time_stamp is also in the argument of MAX().  Hence, loose index scan applies in this case.

Comment: I am still uncertain why it does not do something as or more efficient for the first query, since the second query adds a restriction that it does not need to apply for the first.

Comment: The way I understand it, loose-index scan does not really scan the index.  It skips between between the interesting rows.  Based on the current row, it builds the key to find the next row.  In your first query, there is no specific value for time_stamp.  Hence, it can not build a key that can be used for look-up. For the 2nd query, since MAX value is requested, the end-value of the range specified by the WHERE clause may be used. The target row will then be the first row smaller than this key.  It would be possible to transform the first query into the second, but that is currently not done.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `UNIQUE` with

```
INDEX(has_data, pv_name, time_stamp) -- in this order
```

It is generally better not to make an index `UNIQUE` unless you need the constraint.  In this situation, you already have the subset `(pv_name, time_stamp)` constrained.

When building an index, start with any `=` columns (`has_data`).  This allows the rest of the processing to focus on the necessary data, and not be stumbling over undesirable values of `has_data`.  Put one range (`time_stamp`) last, since nothing (usually) beyond a range can be used.  Having these three columns in the index gives you a "covering" index, so the `EXPLAIN` should say "Using index".

The index I propose should help both queries.

See also [*my index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: The index you propose would **prevent** MySQL from using loose index scan optimization, therefore would **slow down** the query.

Comment: Patrick, can you confirm Shadow's claim?  Shadow, can you elaborate?

Comment: @RickJames Your suggestion appears to help. I have updated the question to show the results of testing it.

Comment: I am still curious why the first query with the original index does not use the 'Using index for group-by' optimization.

Comment: @Patrick apparently you lost the loose index scan on the 2nd query and was replaced by a tight index scan, which is slower solution.

Comment: @Patrick - Could you do an experiment to help with my discussion with Shadow:  (after adding my index)  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ... ; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`  If some handler number(s) look like the number of rows in the table, then "loose scan" was not used.  If the largest numbers are about the number of rows in the resultset, then "loose scan" was _probably used.

Comment: @RickJames I have added the results of the experiment to the question. I should note that your index appears to make both queries run faster than either of the queries with the original index.

Comment: I will also note that the result set is all of the unique pv_names in the table (as expected).

Comment: @Shadow - I _think_ the Handler numbers say that the query is using "loose scan".

Comment: Would the fact that new data is constantly being added to the database affect the experiment?

Comment: I see no timings for the actual runs.  Could you supply such, being careful to specify which indexes existed at the time the timing was taken?  In any case, with InnoDB, simultaneous writes _usually_ have only a small impact on the performance of a `SELECT`.

Comment: @RickJames Updated.

Comment: Oops, I should have warned against the effects of caching.  The _first_ query may be slower because of hitting the disk some of the time; then the _second_ had the advantage of the blocks already being in cache.  (Run each a couple of times.)

Comment: The run times remain approximately the same even after running each query multiple times (with the original index).

Comment: It is true that loose index scan will not be used for the index suggest by Rick.   As stated in the documentation, for loose-index scan to be used, the columns of GROUP BY must be a prefix of the index.   However, since rows with has_data=0 seems not to be very frequent in this table, scanning the index for just those rows, should be much cheaper than loose index scan on the entire index.

Answer (score -1):

Under some specific conditions it is possible to optimize the group-by. And thats what happens in the second query. The optimization is called loose-table-index scan ([see MySQL-Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html))

Maybe this will work too if you use DISTINCT in your first query instead of group by? Or you could look in the Documentation how you could achieve that group-by optimization for the first query.

> **Loose Index Scan**
>
> The most efficient way to process GROUP BY is when an index is used to directly retrieve the grouping columns. With this access method, MySQL uses the property of some index types that the keys are ordered (for example, BTREE). This property enables use of lookup groups in an index without having to consider all keys in the index that satisfy all WHERE conditions. This access method considers only a fraction of the keys in an index, so it is called a loose index scan. When there is no WHERE clause, a loose index scan reads as many keys as the number of groups, which may be a much smaller number than that of all keys. If the WHERE clause contains range predicates (see the discussion of the range join type in Section 9.8.1, “Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN”), a loose index scan looks up the first key of each group that satisfies the range conditions, and again reads the least possible number of keys. This is possible under the following conditions:
>
> - The query is over a single table.
> - The GROUP BY names only columns that form a leftmost prefix of the index and no other columns. (If, instead of GROUP BY, the query has a DISTINCT clause, all distinct attributes refer to columns that form a leftmost prefix of the index.) For example, if a table t1 has an index on (c1,c2,c3), loose index scan is applicable if the query has GROUP BY c1, c2,. It is not applicable if the query has GROUP BY c2, c3 (the columns are not a leftmost prefix) or GROUP BY c1, c2, c4 (c4 is not in the index).
> - The only aggregate functions used in the select list (if any) are MIN() and MAX(), and all of them refer to the same column. The column must be in the index and must immediately follow the columns in the GROUP BY.
> - Any other parts of the index than those from the GROUP BY referenced in the query must be constants (that is, they must be referenced in equalities with constants), except for the argument of MIN() or MAX() functions.
>
> For columns in the index, full column values must be indexed, not just a prefix. For example, with `c1 VARCHAR(20), INDEX (c1(10))`, the index cannot be used for loose index scan.
> If loose index scan is applicable to a query, the EXPLAIN output shows Using index for group-by in the Extra column.

Hope this helps

Comment: The group-by is equivalent to using distinct in the first query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: I guess I understand that it is using this optimization, but it seems strange that it can't do something as or more efficient for the first.

Comment: I understand what u mean, but is it really a problem for you to have one column more?

Comment: The 2nd query uses the loose index scan optimisation, but this answer fails to explain why the 1st does not use it. Based on my experience (and the documentation) it should.